# Как объяснить расстановку знаков препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Меня очень волнует отсутствие патриотизма у некоторой части нашей молодёжи, с одной стороны, и подмена патриотизма узким местничеством — с другой.

Answer (score 3):

*С одной стороны* — вводное сочетание. Здесь оно находится в середине предложения, поэтому отделяется запятыми.

Тире поставлено перед *с другой*, потому что здесь пропущено слово *стороны*.

**Вводные сочетания с одной стороны, с другой стороны выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми**: ...Генерал не хотел допускать и того, чтобы дивизия его перестала существовать. С другой стороны, он знал, что выполнит свой долг до конца (Фад.); С одной стороны, ты прав, но, с другой стороны, ты должен принять во внимание и мою точку зрения (газ.). **При пропуске слова *стороны* ставится тире**: С одной стороны, знания студента были глубокими, с другой — они оказались очень односторонними.

http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=291